# Two-way data binding for array collection in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder

I am using flex 3.5 sdk. I want to bind an array collection to a form. The structure of array collection is like this.

```
MyClass :
var value : String;
var arr : ArrayCollection;

Each element in arr above is an object of MySecondClass

MySecondClass :
var val1 : String;
var val2 : String;
var val3 : String;
```

I want to bind array collection of MyClass objects (two-way) to a form which has a table and another table inside this table.

How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: You means to edit the table cell and the data in the array also changed? PS. You are using datagrid?

Comment: I m using a repeater and a tilelist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try set the var in MySecondClass to binable.

```
public class MySecondClass {
....
[bindable]
public var1:String;
[bindable]
public var2:String;
[bindable]
public var3:String;
}
```

If you change the value of the object, the cell associated with this data should be change.

//P.S.

Answer after more input from questioner.

You can add the

```
<mx:Binding destination="checkbox.selected" source="data.value"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Thats true however, I want two way data binding. When I change the value in form, I want it to be reflected in the object also.

Comment: What is your form look like? or you use custom item renderer

Comment: Its like an accordion. value from MyClass becomes header and array collection becomes elements with variables in MySecondClass as parameters

Comment: Actually, what is the UI you are using to change the value? And, are you want to have the behaviour like this. Change the data object value -> the accordion and element will refresh.

Comment: Thanks. But what you mentioned is one way binding. Its like the values from objects are displayed, however, when I change these values in UI, they are not reflected in objects. The MySecondClass is used for checkboxes, val1 is the label, val2 is checked flag and val3 is disabled flag. What I want is get values from DB as objects, bind it to UI, when values are changed and clicked 'Submit', store these objects back to DB.

Comment: Here it is <mx:CheckBox label="{data.value}" selected="{(data.val2 == 'Y') ? true : false }" enabled="{(data.val3 == 'Y') ? false : true}" />

Comment: @Correction : Consider val2 and val3 are boolean                                                           <mx:CheckBox label="{data.value}" selected="{data.val2}" enabled="{data.val3}" />                                                    So that way, assume selected was false and I clicked on one checkbox, now selected becomes true and and corresponding object gets updated.

Comment: You can add the <mx:Binding destination="checkbox.selected" source="data.value"/>

Comment: Yes but its an issue. Assume there are 5 MyClass objects and each MyClass object has 3 MySecondClass objects. Each MySecondClass object must be bound. So where should I put the binding tag ?

Comment: I don't known if you are using a custom itemRenderer. If you are using a custom itemRenderer, you can do the binding within.

Comment: I am using custom item renderer only for checkbox. So you are saying I must put binding tag there ?

Comment: Yeah, you can place there. THen each can bind corresponding data to that checkbox.